# inteligently expiring sessions automatically

Tags: php, session

I am trying to code an automatic session timeout function in php, currently, this is what i have

```
if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1200)) {
    // last request was more than 20 minutes ago
    // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

This technique depends on the user loading a page before he is notified of his expiration and i need to check on pageload.

I need one that expires weather the user loads a page or not. This is because other users loggedin to  the site are notified when a session expires, and data is recorded in the database for further use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite complex topic, but you can manage implementing a session handler interface and a database handler.

1. Check session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cookie_lifetime in PHP config

   This is a very good article about session settings: [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)
2. Create the database layer implementing SessionHandlerInterface and session_set_save_handler() with these methods.

   - SessionHandlerInterface::close — Close the session
   - SessionHandlerInterface::destroy — Destroy a session
   - SessionHandlerInterface::gc — Cleanup old sessions
   - SessionHandlerInterface::open — Initialize session
   - SessionHandlerInterface::read — Read session data
   - SessionHandlerInterface::write — Write session data

Tutorial: 
http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Managment-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Finally you can query the database anytime to get offline and online users.